# Docker Container for Windows - desktop app

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

If I create a container with windows image on it, is it possible to use a remote connection to actually see the desktop and , for example, play minesweeper?

My use case is this:

I have hundreds of users. Each user need to create their our infrastructure consisting in about 6 machines linked together. After creating, the user will open some desktop gui apps on each one using a remote desktop connection.

Comment: if no, is it in the roadmap for the future or it is clear that it will never be implemented

Comment: ps: I know it is an unusual use case, but why the downvote?

Comment: Have you ever checked if docker is able to run Windows ?

Comment: Sure...  There is windowsserver image and nano image:  https://forums.docker.com/c/docker-for-windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this isn't something you will be able to do.

There are currently two Windows container images, `microsoft/windowsservercore` and `microsoft/nanoserver`

**nanoserver**

[This blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2016/04/26/deploying-and-configuring-windows-nano-server-2016-tp4/) about TP4 (one of the earlier releases) says

> The only option available when logging into console of a virtual machine running Nano Server or connecting a crash cart to a physical Nano Server is this very plain emergency console

[This section](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/get-started/manage-nano-server) on managing Nano server also states

> Nano Server is managed remotely. There is no local logon capability at all, nor does it support Terminal Services.

There is also [this article](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/04/next-windows-server-offer-new-even-smaller-nano-server-footprint/), admittedly not from Microsoft, about Windows Nano server

> Nano Server strips back the operating system further still, dropping things like the GUI stack, 32-bit Win32 support, local logins, and remote desktop support.
>
> Nano Server is designed for two kinds of workload: cloud apps built on runtimes such as .NET, Java, Node.js, or Python, and cloud infrastructure, such as hosting Hyper-V virtual machines.

**servercore**

Docker blog has a pretty interesting entry
[Introducing Docker for Windows Server 2016](https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/dockerforws2016/). This part addresses the question of GUI apps

> The Windows Server Core image comes with a mostly complete userland with the processes and DLLs found on a standard Windows Server Core install. With the exception of GUI apps and apps requiring Windows Remote Desktop, most apps that run on Windows Server can be dockerized to run in an image based on microsoft/windowsservercore with minimal effort.

---

If you wanted to set up that kind of an environment, one option is to use something like [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/) to orchestrate starting and provisioning regular windows VMs. Though 6 windows VMs will not be easy on memory.

Comment: You're right that there's no UI for Windows containers, but containers don't have to be based from Nano Server. You can use [microsoft/nanoserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/nanoserver/) **or** [microsoft/windowsservercore](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/) as the base image - the later has the full Windows Server Core feature set, minus the UI.

Comment: @EltonStoneman Thank you, that was a pretty big omission on my part. Should be fixed.

Comment: My guess is that adding UI for windows containers should configure a threat to Microsoft, since you could use windows without paying license. Thats why they don't add it, (and of course, it is a non critical use case)

Comment: @guilhermecgs Not really, the goal behind Windows containers is the same as behind Linux containers, more easily package and deploy your applications to hundreds of servers at a time. A GUI isn't very helpful in that scenario.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, but you can do it with linux :-)  http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/   But I get it, it is a rather bizarre use case

Comment: @guilhermecgs You're right, and there's a really interesting blog post on why you would want to run desktop applications inside containers [here](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/). That's just not a use case Microsoft is targeting (at the moment).